# Merging configurations from the PDE orgs to a single beta packaging org (2) using a Salesforce migration tool

Tags: appexchange, app

In terms of appexchange development, you merge configurations from the PDE orgs to a single beta packaging org (2) using a Salesforce migration tool.

What does Salesforce Migration tool means, which tools are there?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) and [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/), either of which are used by many older IDEs (Integrated Development Environment), including Salesforce's own Developer Console, as well as the newer [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli). These APIs are used to retrieve, deploy, and delete metadata in various types of orgs. Note that using the packaging org is a First Generation Managed Package setup, which is largely obsolete. It's recommended that you set up a [Second Generation Managed Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) (2GMP) instead, unless you have a specific reason/limitation you're working around. In a 2GMP, you use one org as the Dev Hub that stores versions of your package, the PDE is used to "reserve" the namespace for all of your 2GMP (which you link to your Dev Hub org), and you use Scratch Orgs for development. In summary, you have a few different options, so you'll want to do some research what you want to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification in detail.